# Delegate in Swift-language

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8

I have two controllers and i need call up function the first controller to second controller:
In second controller I have created protocol and init delegate in class:

```
    protocol testProtocol {
        func testDelegate() // this function the first controllers
    }

    class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
        var delegate: testProtocol?
    ....
    }
    @IBAction func testDelegateClicked(sender : AnyObject) {
            delegate?.testDelegate()
        }
```

First Controller

```
        class ViewController: UIViewController, testProtocol {
```

`var secondController: SecondViewController = SecondViewController()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            secondController.delegate = self
        }
        func testDelegate() {
            println("Hello delegate")
        }</pre>`

But function not getting called

Comment: How are you displaying `secondViewController`?

Comment: in the second controller only standard functions (ViewDidLoad and didReceiveMemoryWarning) and button handler I showed

Comment: Also make sure you get a weak reference to the delegate. Properties in swift are strong by default

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am going to make an assumption you are using storyboards. If I am correct, then your issue is that your `secondController`, created in your First Controller, is not the actual one you are presenting. You will need to set `secondController` in your `prepareForSegue:`

#### Second Controller

Unchanged

#### First Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, testProtocol {

    // you will want to add the ? since this variable is now optional (i.e. can be nil)
    var secondController: SecondViewController? // don't assign it a value yet

    // ...

    // implementation of the protocol
    func testDelegate() {
        println("Hello delegate")
    }

    // your prepare for segue
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // get the controller that storyboard has instantiated and set it's delegate
        secondController = segue!.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController
        secondController!.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i use secondController = segue!.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
        secondController.delegate = self;

Comment: @Maria, take a look at my added comment. You will want to add the `?` to the `secondController` variable. If you do this you will need to also have the `as?`

Comment: If we not use storyboard How can Implement @Firo

Comment: @PREMKUMAR, you would just create your new view controller (`var controller = SecondController()`), set it's delegate (`controller.delegate = self`), then lastly present it (`self.navigationController.pushViewController(controller)`)... if you are still having issues let me know!