# Delegate not being called (instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, swift, instantiation

I have 5 instances of CalculatorViewController in my storyboard, but only one with identifier "secondOperationViewController". 3 of them connected with my initial ViewController named ContainerViewController using embed segues.

I want ViewController with identifier "secondOperationViewController" to call method from my ContainerViewController, but I cant correctly instantiate it, so delegate method not being called. Here is part of my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    secondOperationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondOperationViewController") as? CalculatorViewController
    secondOperationViewController!.delegate = self
    println(secondOperationViewController)
}
```

Any suggestions what's wrong here?

Also I found similar question:

[Delegate in Swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059195/delegate-in-swift-language)

I rewrited instantion of my CalculatorViewController to:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        secondOperationViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as? CalculatorViewController
        secondOperationViewController!.delegate = self;
    }
```

It works, but my delegate method is being called from all 3 ViewControllers, connected to initial ViewController, so I need another solution.

So how can I call delegate method exactly from ViewController with specified identifier? Any ideas?

---

**So, embed segue doesn't work with "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" (but works with modal presented segue). I dont know why. Here is solution for embed segue:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let secondOperationViewController:CalculatorViewController = childViewControllers[0] as CalculatorViewController
    secondOperationViewController.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the storyboard give your segue a unique identifier:

[image]

Then in your `prepareForSegue` check against that before you set the delegate, this way you know exactly when you will be setting up this delegate.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Checking to make sure this is the correct segue. This is also protection for the "as?"
    if segue?.identifier == "SecondOVCSeuge" {
        secondOperationViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as? CalculatorViewController
        secondOperationViewController!.delegate = self;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Hm. It should work for my connected ViewControllers. But what with ViewController that dont have a segue? I want to use delegate method to switch between SecondOperationViewController (with embed segue from ContainerViewController), firstOperationViewController and thirdOperationViewController (without any segue).

Comment: @Kenarius1 in that case you can check the `ViewController`'s `identifier`. `secondOperationViewController.identifier == "secondOperationViewController"` (per your first example).

Comment: But how can I instantiate ViewController without a segue? Should I try to create a segue programmatically? In Objective-C I used 'self.firstOperationViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstOperationViewController"]' but seems that it doesn't work with delegate in Swift.

Comment: @Kenarius1 No just do: `self.firstOVC = OperationViewController()`. You do not need to use storyboard to instantiate all of your controllers.

Comment: If I instantiate ViewController with: 'firstOperationViewController = CalculatorViewController(); firstOperationViewController.delegate = self' then my delegate method doesn't work again. So I think that I need 3 properties, each of them instantiated with it's own identifier. The problem, is that instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier don't works in Swift as it works in Objective-C.