# Firing a function whenever static variable value changed

Tags: xcode, swift, function, core-bluetooth

I'm developing a iPhone apps using swift to communicate with another device via bluetooth. My question is I want to fire a function on another class(change the display value) whenever the variable received new data from CoreBluetooth. Can someone helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wei

Implement delegate to perform it

write a protocol

```
protocol ValueChangedDelegate {
  func valueChanged(nValue:Int)
}
```

and implement that protocol in the View controller where you want the new value

```
class YourCustomClass: ValueChangedDelegate 
{
  func valueChanged(nValue:Int) {
    print("value changed")
  }
}
```

then implement a delegate and set the delegate to self and call the method when value changes, then all the classes that implement the protocol will receive the new value

You can refer this 
[Delegate in Swift-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059195/delegate-in-swift-language)

Comment: Yup, i have tried to add in the delegate method but function is not fired.

Comment: i can't figure out which part i have missed out

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished one of two ways, either using KVO or the NSNotificationCenter. In this instance it may be best to go with KVO since you're only listening to a single property.

Answer (score 2):

**-** I will prefer doing the things in `Swift` way by using `didSet`

**Example:**

```
var value: Int?
{
    didSet
    {
        print("I just got changed")
    }
}

value = 10
```

**-** In `Swift` we use `didSet` to update the UI as soon as there is a change in the `model`.

**-** In the above example as soon as the variable `value` is set to 10, its `didSet` is fired.

**-** Similarly you can use this to handle the Bluetooth value